# how to make bootstrap popover like google app launch button?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

How to make a range item inside bootstrap popover? I want to make it the exact same as the google app launch button as the following image:

[image]

I played around CSS and Try to get it as close as possible, but it seems I am doing it in a wrong way. https://jsfiddle.net/ueskyj1u/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import "compass/css3";
    .popover-content {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .popover-footer {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 18px;
        background-color: #F7F7F7;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }

    .flex-container {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .flex-item {
        background: tomato;
        /*    padding: 13px;*/
        width: 74px;
        ;
        height: 83px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: center;
    }


    /*---------------------*/

    #General {
        background: #383a35;
    }

    #sale {
        background: #ffde6b;
    }

    #Servicing {
        background: #762963;
    }

    #Purchasing {
        background: #22d65b;
    }

    #Billing {
        background: #67a0e1;
    }

    #Accounts {
        background: #a22ee3;
    }

    #GST {
        background: #39c5ac;
    }

    #StockControl {
        background: #ef5836;
    }

    #System {
        background: #69cbf5;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div>

            <!--             <div class="flex-container">
                    <div id="General" class="flex-item"> 1
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sale" class="flex-item">
                        <div class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </div> 2</div>
                    <div id="Servicing" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe "> </div> 3</div>
                    <div id="Purchasing" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </div> 4</div>
                    <div id="Billing" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="  glyphicon glyphicon-usd"> </div> 5</div>
                    <div id="Accounts" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="  glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </div> 6</div>
                    <div id="GST" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="  glyphicon glyphicon-stats"> </div> 7</div>
                    <div id="StockControl" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </div> 8</div>
                    <div id="StockControl" class="flex-item">
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"> </div> 8</div>
                </div>
      -->
        </div>
        <a href="#" rel="details" class="btn btn-small pull-left" data-toggle="popover">click me to see popover</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[rel=details]").popover({
            trigger: 'click',
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: 'true',
            content: '<div class="flex-container"><div id="General" class="flex-item">  1<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></div></div><div id="sale" class="flex-item"><div class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </div>  2</div><div id="Servicing" class="flex-item"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe "> </div> 3</div><div id="Purchasing" class="flex-item"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></div>4</div><div id="Billing" class="flex-item"><div class="  glyphicon glyphicon-usd"> </div>  5</div><div id="Accounts" class="flex-item"><div class="  glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </div>6</div><div id="GST" class="flex-item"><div class="  glyphicon glyphicon-stats"> </div>7</div><div id="StockControl" class="flex-item"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></div> 8</div><div id="StockControl" class="flex-item"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"> </div> 8</div></div>',

            template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
        });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You should replace your non-code portion of text, with your actual code. Your JSFiddle link, isn't a link because of this, and will make most users annoyed (in my opinion).

Comment: i just noticed that ,fix aready

Answer (score 2):

Do changes in popup template

```
<div class="popover">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content"></div>
    <div class="footer">
        <center>
            <a href="" >more</a>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

add class

```
.footer{
      width: 101%;
    margin-left: -0.5%;
  background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.48);
  margin-bottom:-1%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ueskyj1u/1/